# How to get the author ID of the current post (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

It seems to be a very simple question, but for some reason, it is not working with me. I tried many ways to get the Author ID of a current post, but nothing works.

I've tried many ways, like those:

```
$author = get_queried_object();
$author_id = $author->ID;
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;  
$author_id = the_author_meta('ID')
$author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
mycred_add('approved_comment', $author_id, 10, 'Pagamento Modelo');
```

I use a similar function and it works, but this function is to get 10 points of current user:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$descontou = mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Tipo de Compra');
```

And this function above is working normally.The first function, should add 10 points to the author of the post, every time the user acess the page (it gets from his and add to author). But this function is adding the 10 points to the admin account, not author (who is not the admin). Maybe someone has an opinion?? Maybe I'm very stupid about this...

Comment: You want to use `$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID')`

Comment: Hello, Disinfor! Thank you very much for comment here. But it also doesn't work. It takes the admin account, and add credit to it, not to the author. :/

Comment: then there is something else going on in your function to attribute credits...since that function gets the author id of the post. The issue is happening somewhere else in your code.